# Execute sql script after jpa/EclipseLink created tables?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

is there a possibility to execute an sql script, after EclipseLink generated the ddl?
In other words, is it possible that the EclipseLink property "eclipselink.ddl-generation" with "drop-and-create-tables" is used and EclipseLink executes another sql-file (to insert some data into some tables just created) after creating the table definition?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.x and JPA 2.0 with GlassFish v3.

Or can I init the tables within a java method which is called on the project (war with ejb3) deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called BEFORE ddl-execution. And there seems to be no nice way to adapt it, as there is no suitable event one could use.

Comment: @Ralph the Pascal's solution

Answer (score 18):

I came across this question for the same reasons, trying to find an approach to run an initialization script after DDL generation. I offer this answer to an old question in hopes of shortening the amount of "literary research" for those looking for the same solution.

I'm using GlassFish 4 with its default EclipseLink 2.5 JPA implementation. The new Schema Generation feature under JPA 2.1 makes it fairly straightforward to specify an "initialization" script after DDL generation is completed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="cbesDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/cbesPool</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/load_script.sql"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The above configuration generates DDL scripts from metadata (i.e. annotations) after which the `META-INF/sql/load_script.sql` script is run to populate the database. In my case, I seed a few tables with test data and generate additional views.

Additional information on EclipseLink's use of JPA's properties can be found in the DDL Generation section of [EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21). Likewise, [Section 37.5 Database Schema Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro005.htm) in Oracle's Java EE 7 Tutorial and [TOTD #187](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_schema_generation) offer a quick introduction also.

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at [Running a SQL Script on startup in EclipseLink](http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-script-on-startup-in.html) that describes a solution presented as a kind of equivalent to Hibernate's `import.sql` feature<sup>1</sup>. Credits to Shaun Smith:

> ### [Running a SQL Script on startup in EclipseLink](http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-script-on-startup-in.html)
>
> Sometimes, when working with DDL
>   generation it's useful to run a script
>   to clean up the database first. In
>   Hibernate if you put a file called
>   "import.sql" on your classpath its
>   contents will be sent to the database.
>   Personally I'm not a fan of magic
>   filenames but this can be a useful
>   feature.
>
> There's no built in support for this
>   in EclipseLink but it's easy to do
>   thank's to EclipseLink's high
>   extensibility. Here's a quick solution
>   I came up with: I simply register an
>   event listener for the session
>   postLogin event and in the handler I
>   read a file and send each SQL
>   statement to the database--nice and
>   clean. I went a little further and
>   supported setting the name of the file
>   as a persistence unit property. You
>   can specify this all in code or in the
>   persistence.xml.
>
> The `ImportSQL` class is configured as
>   a `SessionCustomizer` through a
>   persistence unit property which, on
>   the `postLogin` event, reads the file
>   identified by the "import.sql.file"
>   property. This property is also
>   specified as a persistence unit
>   property which is passed to
>   `createEntityManagerFactory`. This
>   example also shows how you can define
>   and use your own persistence unit
>   properties.
>
> ```
> import org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer;
> import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
> import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.SessionEvent;
> import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.SessionEventAdapter;
> import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.UnitOfWork;
>
> public class ImportSQL implements SessionCustomizer {
>
>     private void importSql(UnitOfWork unitOfWork, String fileName) {
>         // Open file
>         // Execute each line, e.g.,
>         // unitOfWork.executeNonSelectingSQL("select 1 from dual");
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
>         session.getEventManager().addListener(new SessionEventAdapter() {
>             @Override
>             public void postLogin(SessionEvent event) {
>                 String fileName = (String) event.getSession().getProperty("import.sql.file");
>                 UnitOfWork unitOfWork = event.getSession().acquireUnitOfWork();
>                 importSql(unitOfWork, fileName);
>                 unitOfWork.commit() 
>             }    
>         });
>     }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>
>     // Enable DDL Generation
>     properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION, PersistenceUnitProperties.DROP_AND_CREATE);
>     properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_GENERATION_MODE, PersistenceUnitProperties.DDL_DATABASE_GENERATION);
>     // Configure Session Customizer which will pipe sql file to db before DDL Generation runs
>     properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, "model.ImportSQL");
>     properties.put("import.sql.file","/tmp/someddl.sql");
>
>     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
>             .createEntityManagerFactory("employee", properties);
> }
> ```

I'm not sure it's a strict equivalent though, I'm not sure the script will run after the database generation. Testing required. If it doesn't, maybe it can be adapted.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Hibernate has a neat little feature that is heavily under-documented and unknown. You can execute an SQL script during the SessionFactory creation right after the database schema generation to import data in a fresh database. You just need to add a file named import.sql in your classpath root and set either create or create-drop as your hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the heavily under-documented and unknown feature!

Comment: @javydreamercsw: I've pasted the content.

Comment: It's an honour to be cited. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might help as there is a confusion here:
Use exactly the same set of properties (except logger) for data seeding.

DO NOT USE:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
```

DO USE:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
```

I confirm this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

:) Just substitue with your data

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/seed.sql"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This process offers executing sql before DDL statments whereas what would be nice (for example, to insert seed data ) is to have something which executes after DDL statements. I don't if I am missing something here. Can somebody please tell me how to execute sql AFTER eclipselink has created tables (when create-tables property is set to tru)

Comment: It seems, that eclipse can't do it (right now - in future releases maybe). Your question was exact the same as my initial one. I haven't found an aswer yet. If you, please post!