# JPA removes MySql triggers

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, eclipselink, toplink

Because my persistence.xml uses `drop-and-create-tables`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="USENETPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.NewsgroupsArticles</class>
    <class>net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Article</class>
    <class>net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Newsgroup</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nntp"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="java"/>
      <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My triggers get removed each run.  Where can I put the triggers so that they're not removed?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `SessionCustomizer`. And within your persistence properties you should insert a property pointing your `SessionCustomizer` implementation.

```
properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, MySessionCustomizer.class.getName());
```

or

```
<property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="foo.bar.MySessionCustomizer" />
```

and within this session customizer you could load your trigger codes and let it be executed with:

```
unitOfWork.executeNonSelectingSQL(sql);
```

A detailed explanation regarding this topic you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731513/1001027)