# Delete database tables programmatically

Tags: database, jpa, eclipselink

My application created database tables using JPA. I want to delete these tables programmatically using JPA and/or EclipseLink API (without using `DROP TABLE` command).
What is the right way to delete database tables created by JPA framework?

Comment: Similar one, can refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2731513/366964

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use JPA 2.1, you can specify that the provider write or read scripts to drop tables, allowing you to control what gets executed.  Unfortunately though, it doesn't give you fine grain control unless you can dynamically write your own drop table scripts.

Without using provider specific code, the only other way to drop a particular table is native SQL.

Within EclipseLink you would get the session from the EntityManager and create a new SchemaManager(session).  With it you can call dropDefaultTables() to drop all tables in the persistence unit, or use dropObject(DatabaseObjectDefinition) to drop single DatabaseObjectDefinition objects which are used to represent tables, stored procs etc.  You can use getDefaultTableCreator(boolean generateFKConstraints) to get the default table creator for the PU.  With it you can use getTableDefinitions() to get all DatabaseObjectDefinition objects representing the tables in the PU, so you can select one to drop.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_access_table.2C_column_and_schema_information_at_runtime.3F 
shows how to unwrap the EM to get the session.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (`EclipseLink JPA 2.1`):

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("you persistence unit"); 
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
SchemaManager sm = new SchemaManager(em.unwrap(DatabaseSession.class));
sm.dropTable("table name");
```