# Standalone JPA sequence

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Through SQL one can define a sequence such as `CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name`.

Can it be defined using JPA? I only know of sequences defined on attributes of entities. I'd like to avoid creating an entity just to be able to define a sequence.

Comment: How are you using that sequence?

Comment: I have a legacy table (in a bad DB scheme) in which I need to identify groups. I can do it with group by, but to keep my queries simple and because I need to add new groups programmatically, I've decided to add an group_id column as a fake 1:N. I need the sequence to autoincrement so I can use it to generate ids for new groups of records.

Comment: You said that you don't like to create an entity for the sequence, but you seem to already have an entity, with the group_id as the column, couldn't you just define the sequence for that field, or do I understand something wrongly?

Comment: If they were unique, than yes. But because of this ugly hack, multiple rows will have the same group_id. If the entity for this table had a attribute-bound sequence, it would increment the sequence with each added row. Therefore, I need to set the group_id programmatically, and increment the sequence with each added group.

Comment: Are you looking for DML generation from JPA or something else? JPA only creates schema's for objects it controls, while the sequence you are looking to use isn't for an entity's identity, so isn't in the spec. JPA 2.1 can execute scripts for you, which would allow you to include the sequence creation in a separate file - there are a number of posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760864/496099 showing how. Your next question will likely be how to get the value from it though - if it isn't for entity identity, you'll have to use native sql or JPA provider specific code

Comment: No, it's definitely DDL. If it's within the JPA spec to create DDL for attribute-bound sequences, why not standalone sequences? Because I don't have the entire JPA spec in my head, I'm asking if what I want is there. It appears not.

Comment: TBH I'd recommend against using schema generation for 'non-standalone' sequences. Or for generating anything at all, for that matter. You'd be better off using a DB migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create it on start up.
From [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) documentation:

> Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and data.sql

For example put SEQUENCE creation into `data.sql`

Comment: Thank you, it's a valid solution. I'd like to leave the question hanging though, because I feel like this should be implemented in JPA.